# htaccess file make redirection to another file

Tags: .htaccess

I have htaccess file below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

Redirect /index.html /login.html

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html


Options -Indexes
```

Redirect /index.html /login.html

When user enters index page it should redirect to login.html page.
But it doesn't work.

Comment: What URL is being requested by the user?

Comment: I'm asking what URL-path you are requesting, not the domain name. And adding the domain name to that directive in the way you have done does not make sense (and is certainly incorrect).

Comment: im requesting /index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Redirect /index.html /login.html
> ```
>
> im requesting `/index`

If you are requesting `/index` then I'm not sure why you are checking for `/index.html` in your rule. However, you should be using mod_rewrite to construct this redirect since you are already using mod_rewrite for your internal rewrites.

So, have it like this instead:

```
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect "/index" to "/login"
RewriteRule ^index$ /login [R=302,L]

# Append ".html" if target file exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [L]
```

I've also "fixed" your `.html` rewrite since this could result in a 500 error for certain requests and there's no need to check that the request does not map to a directory before checking that the request does map to a file.

See the following question on ServerFault that expands on this potential issue regarding `.html` removal. https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error

Comment: I just tried this and it still doesn't redirect, i'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Make sure you've cleared your browser cache. Are your custom error documents working OK? Just try adding some nonsense to the top of the file - do you get an error?

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: What about what I mentioned in my comment above...? It's possible that your `.htaccess` file isn't doing anything.